# View em Django não retorna objeto HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, crud

Estou fazendo um CRUD simples em Django para fins de aprendizado. Porém, estou tendo um problema. Ao criar uma view para adicionar dados em uma agenda, o servidor retorna o seguinte erro:

> The view agenda.views.adiciona didn't return an HttpResponse object.

Segue o código da view "adiciona" que escrevi:

```
def adiciona(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormItemAgenda(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            dados = form.cleaned_data
            item = ItemAgenda(data=dados['data'], hora=dados['hora'], titulo=dados['titulo'], descricao=dados['descricao'])
            item.save()
            return render_to_response("salvo.html", {})
        else:
            form = FormItemAgenda()
        return render_to_response("adiciona.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Defini as rotas em "urls.py" da seguinte maneira:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'agenda.views.lista'),
    url(r'^adiciona/$', 'agenda.views.adiciona'),
)
```

Procurei no Google e na documentação do Django 1.6.x e não encontrei nenhuma resposta significativa. Como posso corrigir esse erro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o seu código é somente esse mostrado, então o que parece estar faltando é um `else` para tratar de requisições e não de um `post`. De fato, o `render_to_response` retorna um `HttpResponse` e, caso o problema fosse uma exceção, a mensagem de erro seria outra. O que pode estar acontecendo então é a sua view estar sendo chamada com outro método HTTP (provavelmente `get`) e - como não tem `else` - ela estar retornando `None`.

Experimente, no final do método, colocar uma resposta padrão caso a visão não reconheça o método:

```
def adiciona(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Método inválido para essa operação: {}'.format(request.method))
```

Comment: Obrigado por tirar minha dúvida. De fato ele retornou a mensagem indicando método GET. Agora preciso descobrir como fazer para que o formulário passe o método POST, como deveria ser...

Answer (score 0):

```
def adiciona(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormCrud(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response("salvo.html",{})
    else:
        form = FormCrud() 

    return render_to_response("adiciona.html",{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que esse código faz?